# Electron: Read/Write External Files / run External apps

Tags: electron, electron-builder

**Context:**
I have an application `ExternalApp.exe` that needs to read a file to execute: `File.ini`. This file has configurations for the `ExternalApp.exe` app and is not human-readable.

**Solution:**
Create an `electron` app to read/write `File.ini` and execute `ExternalApp.exe`.
Build an `electron` `portable` app using `electron-builder` and move the generated .exe (`Launcher.exe`) to the `ExternalApp` folder.

We end up with this:

```
[ExternalApp] (folder)
    |-- ExternalApp.exe
    |-- File.ini
    |-- Launcher.exe (electron app)
```

**Issues:**
This is working just fine while developing and running `npm start`, no issues, but when I compile the app into my executable, tries to read `File.ini` from `AppData` and not from the `ExternalApp` folder.

Not sure what I'm doing wrong. Here is the code:

Open the external `ExternalApp.exe`

```
const {shell} = require('electron');
shell.openExternal('./ExternalApp.exe').then(response => {
    console.log(response);
});
```

Result:

```
undefined //Instead, the Windows Explorer is opened.
```

---

Read `File.ini` file

```
const fs = require('fs');
const file_info = './File.ini';
fs.readFile(file_info , 'utf8', function(error, data){
    if (error) throw error;
    console.info(data)
});
```

Result:

```
Uncaught Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\Personal\AppData\Local\Temp\2VBLMOYLXHt0I5WQNGDXIPttjAW\File.ini'
```

Note: Im new in Electron, this is my first project using it, any help will be much apreciated

Comment: `shell.openExternal()` is not meant to run executables. Have a look at NodeJS' [child_process](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html) module. As for the other issue, it *seems* as though the portable app is first unpacked to a temporary location and then run from there, but I can't confirm that. You could play around and see if [`app.getAppPath("exe")`](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/app#appgetapppath) helps you to do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution in another post, should use `PORTABLE_EXECUTABLE_DIR` to get the right path

```
process.env.PORTABLE_EXECUTABLE_DIR
```

Thanks @alexander for reviewing it